# Is milk from germany considered Cholov Stam?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, dairy, modern-times

Shalom guys! 
I'm writing this to ask if milk imported from Germany is considered Cholov Stam. Particularly that milk sold on Aldi stores.

Reason I'm asking is because you almost don't find Kosher food in the supermarket around here and have to resort to checking online lists to know.

*Edit* Sorry guys, I'm in Europe and forgot that might've been relevant. I also live in an area without significant Jewish presence, and definitively no rabbis!

*Edit* I am asking about Germany in particular, not all of Europe.

Comment: From you addition, you need to specify where in Europe you are located, what precisely is being imported and what kashrus organizations in your country are available to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Always consult a local rabbi for the 'real' answer, but according to the [german kashrut-list](http://kaj-berlin.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Kahal_Adass_Jisroel_Koscherliste_2016.pdf), page 7:

> Reine Kuh-, Schafs- oder Ziegenmilch, Vollmilch, bzw. Teil- oder
>   entrahmte Milch, ohne Zutaten ist erlaubt

Which would mean that any pure full cow's, sheep's, or goat's milk without added ingredients would be allowed (chalav stam). The document lists several pages of brands with milkproducts with the specification of whether a specific product is allowed and those are also given the predicate 'chalav stam' in the document.

To reiterate: when in doubt: consult the rabbinate. If a product is on the list it can be assumed to be safe, but always remind yourself that products can change more quickly than lists are updated.

Another important disclaimer: you write about import. Always be doubtful of imported products: the product may be made in different factories, even in the same country, that has not been supervised by the rabbinate. When in doubt: compare factorynumbers and discuss with your local rabbi.